# building for OSX, but linking in object file built for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, gcc, arm

On an inhouse Mac Mini we previously had a configuration where we could build our software (mostly in C) so it could be used on devices with ARM chips running iOS.  The build used makefiles that invoked a gcc binary that was present within a /Developer hierarchy.  I'm told this /Developer hierarchy was from an old version of Apple's Xcode tool.

Recently we had a contractor upgrade this Mac Mini to OS X v10.10.5.  Sorry, I can't remember what older version of OS X it was running before.  This upgrade wiped out the /Developer hierarchy.  I tried copying the /Developer hierarchy from the backup disk that the contractor created, but attempting to do the same iOS for ARM build using it fails under the newer OS X; I get a "no assemblers installed" message.

The contractor suggested installing Xcode v7.2.1, which is the most recent version of Xcode that can work with OS X v10.10.5.  We did this install, but the hierarchy for the newer Xcode (now in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer) doesn't seem to include a cross compiling version of gcc that can run on OS X on x64 but produce code for iOS on ARM.

The contractor suggested trying the build with the regular /usr/bin/gcc and specifying the same qualifiers (e.g., -isysroot) that were used before, obviously adjusted for the newer Xcode hierarchy.  I've tried that, but I'm now getting the error message in the title as soon as the build tries to create dynamic libraries.

So it appears I need some kind of cross compiler to complete this build.  I'm afraid I'm something of an Apple novice.  How can I obtain a proper cross compiler for this build?